# How to retrieve data from html5 output tag into php variable?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a output tag in my html code , which is a mathematical calculation from two inputs

```
<form oninput="duyd.value = (+tot.value)-(+paid.value);"action="createinvoice.php" method="post" name="my-form">
<output name="tot" for="subtot lasdue" id="tot" ></output>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
now i was to use this output data into a php variable . For example 

    $tot = $_POST['tot'];
```

But itsnt working . any solution ?

Got the solution -_-

Instead of output tag , just use input tag using same id and name . also check the for part

```
 <input type="text" id="duyd" name="dued" for="tot paid">
```

Comment: `<output>` tags are not posted, but you could use JavaScript to insert the content into a hidden `<input>` upon submission. What have you tried so far?

Comment: How are you sending the data from the browser to the PHP file? Are you submitting a form or using ajax (`$_POST` has issues with ajax, be sure to set the correct HTTP Content-Type in the request https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php )? Tutorial for forms: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp , tutorial for ajax: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Comment: So far i tried a hidden <input> tag . but didnt work

Comment: @flen i am just using normal Post type data submission .

Comment: Then please post the relevant bit of HTML code that reflects that. That is, edit your question and insert the HTML code that has the form. You should submit the form clicking on the `<input type="submit">` button

Comment: @flen check now . forms are added

Comment: But what exactly isn't working? What appears in the browser's console when you click on submit? The PHP code gets you nothing or displays an error? Is `$tot` an undefined variable?

Comment: What is shown if you run `var_dump(isset($tot)); `?

Comment: @flen $tot shows empty . I got the solution. check the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of output tag , just use input tag using same id and name . also check the for part

```
 <input type="text" id="duyd" name="dued" for="tot paid">
```

Comment: I'm not clear how that helps. In your code, there is no element named "paid", there's nothing that will set the `<output>` contents, and PHP is not handling any input named "dued". Can you post the full working solution?

Comment: ignore those it or names. I just copied so forgot to change. My point is instead of Output tag if you use input tag , it will work simply

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution using JavaScript to populate a hidden `<input>` as well as the `<output>`:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('my-form');
form.addEventListener('input', function() {
  this.tot.value = this.tot_display.value = this.subtot.value - this.lasdue.value;
});
```

```html
<form action="//httpbin.org/post" method="post" id="my-form">
  <input type="text" name="subtot">
  <input type="text" name="lasdue">
  <input type="hidden" name="tot">
  <output name="tot_display"></output>
  <input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here's an example of what's posted:

```
{
  "submitted": "Submit",
  "subtot": "5",
  "lasdue": "1",
  "tot": "4"
}
```

Comment: Got an easy solution with html . check the main post

Answer (score 1):

You can read it by:

```
const alpha = document.querySelector('form.inverse output[name=tot]').value;
```