# How to get hidden array value from output to PHP

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I got an output array code,

```
<output class="gst" id="op" name="Gst[]">0.00</output>
```

i got an input hidden array code,

```
<input type="hidden" id="gst2" name="Gst2[]">
```

I got a function to show the amount of gst for each output

```
function myFunction() {
  debugger
  var ele = document.querySelectorAll('input.input');
  let sum = 0;
  ele.forEach(input => {
    sum += input.value ? parseFloat(input.value) : 0;
    $(input).parents("tr").find(".gst").text((input.value * 0.07).toFixed(2));
  });
  document.getElementById('result').textContent = sum.toFixed(2);
}
```

my problem is, how do i get the hidden array gst2 value in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get de hidden field value in PHP without wrapping it in a form and do a POST / GET request. You could do something like this:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="hidden" id="gst2" name="Gst2[]">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

After you submit the form $_POST['Gst2'] will be set and you can use that variable. You could do the same with method="GET".

EDIT: 
You can find multiple solutions in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50412517/2075596

Just use input tag using same id and name.

Comment: I know this, but i want to get the output value. For this example, https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_output ,how to get the output and use it as variable in PHP?

Comment: I added a link to a post that has multiple solutions